# Is a default value for the first argument for a multi-argument function redundant?

Tags: php, syntax

I've seen code a few times like this

```
function my_func( $arg1 = '', $arg2, $arg3 ) { ...
```

There really is no way to use the default value for `$arg`, right? Since `$arg2` and more are required, you're always going to have to specify a value for `$arg1`, correct? Which would mean that `$arg1` would never use its default value?

Comment: This isn't allowed in Python at all, nor do I see any use to this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP throws a strict warning and it is highly discouraged. However, it behaves like the first argument isn't optional. So at all you are right: The default value is never used, except you set it yourself (what doesn't feel like a default value anymore).

Comment: Agreed. You can pass a preset value in as the first argument if you're working with legacy code and write a handler in the function (i.e. pass in NULL for the first value and then have an is_null($arg1) clause, but it's best to re-order the arguments in the function definition.

Answer (score 1):

yes, you are right it is wrong to do so, even though php doesn't shows any error or warning in such case but any good ide will show warning...

[image]

Comment: PHP will trigger a `E_STRICT`-warning, when you configure it right.